# How I can fix view height on emulator Swift xcode?

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm totally new in ios development and I try to build some interface. Below you can see how it looks at xcode and previews:

[image]

And I have some problems when I run this app on emulator:

[image]

I can't understand why it happens because as I see on preview everything have to be good. I also see such warnings in logs:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000017d1c70 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fca37f16ce0.height == 667   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e3930 UIView:0x7fca37f16fc0.height == 1   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e3a70 UIView:0x7fca37f17130.height == 56   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e6d50 UIView:0x7fca37f17130.top == UILayoutGuide:0x600000de8c40'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e6e40 UIView:0x7fca37f16fc0.centerY == UIView:0x7fca37f16ce0.centerY - 272   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e6e90 V:[UIView:0x7fca37f17130]-(5)-[UIView:0x7fca37f16fc0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e3f70 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(20)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600000de8c40'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fca37f16ce0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e3a70 UIView:0x7fca37f17130.height == 56   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

As I understood the problem is here:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e3930 UIView:0x7fca37f16fc0.height == 1   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000017e3a70 UIView:0x7fca37f17130.height == 56   (active)>",
```

what means that one view has two sizes. But I can't realize how to fix it :( I tried to add priority but it didn't help me. Maybe someone will see my error?

### UPDATE

It seems that I have found problematic constraint:

[image]

when I delete it all my labels are on their normal places, but my gray view overlap system bar, it seems that when I remove safe area I remove smth like margin top. Maybe this info will help to solve this problem?

Comment: firstly, ensure that first two labels are inside the grey view 
secondly, add constraint for orange line to be below the grey view by (x) value

Comment: @MohammedGomaa, I have updated my question, can you check it please?

Comment: Top margin should be exist, grey view should have (top, left, right and height constraints) , first label should have (top, left and height constraint), second label same and both them ensure that they are inside grey view and constraints of them are corresponding to grey view, orange line should be below grey view and rest is the same.. please correct me if I understand your question wrongly.

Comment: In general you are right :) Everything has to be similar to my canvas version, but I have problem with safe area top margin which cause errors mentioned above. When I remove top margin which is connected with safe area my errors disappear